# \usepackage{polyglossia} and bibliography formatting issue

Tags: biblatex

Hi here is my MWE of a problem I've encountered since switching from `\usepackage[greek, UKenglish]{babel}` to `\usepackage{polyglossia}` as below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt ]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,hebrew}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
urlfrom = {available at},
}

 \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
\bibsentence\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}.%
\addspace
\bibsentence\bibstring{urlfrom}%
\addcolon\space
\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate} . 
{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\bibliography{zotero.bib} 
\begin{document}
   hello world \parencite{barth_church_2001}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

The bibliographical reference now no longer formats correctly; it should look like this:

> Barth, K. (2001). Church dogmatics: the doctrine of creation. Ed. by G. Bromiley and T.F. Torrance (H. Knight, G. Bromiley, J.K.S. Reid, and R.H. Fuller. Trans.). Vol. III.2. Edinburgh: T & T Clark. [Online]. Available at: https://books.google.co.uk/.

but instead, is formatted as:

> Barth, K. (2001). Church dogmatics: the doctrine of creation. Ed. by G. Bromiley and T.F. Torrance (H. Knight, G. Bromiley, J.K.S. Reid, and R.H. Fuller. Trans.). Vol. III.2. Edinburgh: T & T Clark. **online**. Available at: https://books.google.co.uk/.

I can add the square brackets to the`\bibsentence\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{[online]}.%` which solves one issue, but doesn't correct the lower case and bold font.

The `.bib` file is

```
@book{barth_church_2001,
    location = {Edinburgh},
    title = {Church Dogmatics: The Doctrine of Creation},
    volume = {{III}.2},
    url = {https://books.google.co.uk/},
    publisher = {T \& T Clark},
    author = {Barth, Karl},
    editor = {Bromiley, G.W. and Torrance, T F},
    translator = {Knight, H and Bromiley, G.W. and Reid, J K S and Fuller, R H},
    date = {2001},
}
```

Comment: `biblatex` and `polyglossia` only work together properly in the newest versions. Update your system to make sure you have at least `biblatex` v3.14/Biber v2.14 and `polyglossia` v1.46. With a fully updated system I get what appears to be the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe I'd already checked the packages were up to date via Texlive, but it appears I was using an outdated/broken repository. Swapped to a new mirror and all is good!

Comment: Why are you switching to polyglossia?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am wring a thesis that includes multiple languages and a mixture of RTL and LTR text that needs to appear inline. After playing around the above solution seemed to deliver what I need, after the update . Although I'm sure now fully updated that there is a solution using `babel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a long time `biblatex` and `polyglossia` did not work together very well. A short while ago `polyglossia` development picked up steam again and considerable effort by the new development team meant that a number of features required for `biblatex` support was implemented.

**If you want to use `polyglossia` and `biblatex` you need an up-to-date system. `biblatex` should be at version 3.14 or above (thus Biber would need to be at v2.14 or above) and `polyglossia` at v1.46 or above.**

With a fully updated MikTeX system the slightly modified MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,hebrew}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom = {available at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \bibsentence\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}%
  \addperiod\space
  \bibstring{urlfrom}%
  \addcolon\space
  \url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{barth_church_2001,
  location   = {Edinburgh},
  title      = {Church Dogmatics: The Doctrine of Creation},
  volume     = {{III}.2},
  url        = {https://books.google.co.uk/},
  publisher  = {T \& T Clark},
  author     = {Barth, Karl},
  editor     = {Bromiley, G. W. and Torrance, T. F.},
  translator = {Knight, H. and Bromiley, G. W. and Reid, J. K. S. and Fuller, R. H.},
  date       = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  hello world \parencite{barth_church_2001}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

> Barth, K. (2001). Church dogmatics: the doctrine of creation. Ed. by G.W. Bromiley and T.F. Torrance (H. Knight, G.W. Bromiley, J.K.S. Reid, and R.H. Fuller, Trans.). Vol. III.2. Edinburgh: T & T Clark. [Online]. Available at: https://books.google.co.uk/.

as desired.